# ActiveRecord local/offline scope for association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Sometimes I write code which could be simplified as following:

```
user.items.active.each { |i| ...do something... }
...some stuff...
user.items.recent.each { |i| ...do something else... }
...some other stuff...
user.items.weird.active.each { |i| ...do whatever... }
```

Items are has_many association on user and active, recent and weird are scopes. The problem is that every scope makes a separate call to the database - while if there are only a few items per user it would be much more efficient just to fetch all of them and filter them "offline". So I could rewrite the above as:

```
user.items.select { |i| i.active? }.each { |i| ...do something... }
...some stuff...
user.items.select { |i| i.created_at > 7.days.ago }.each { |i| ...do something else... }
...some other stuff...
user.items.select { |i| i.weirdness > 50 and i.active? }.each { |i| ...do whatever... }
```

Which would do what I want, but just look bad... Defining active_items, recent_items, weird_active_items methods on a user will help a little, but note how much easier it is to combine scopes. Is there a more "Rails way" to do this? Like adding custom methods on a relation maybe?

Comment: Have you tried doing greedy load instead of lazy load?

Comment: How? And how could this help, access through scope can only filter records with SQL and that means hitting the database.